# Undefined offset, CCK field

Tags: 7

I've been getting the following php notice:

Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in include() (line 89 of node--*name*.tpl.php).

Here's the code:

```
<?php
// loops through array to print out addendum pdf's.
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $variable2 = "../sites/default/files/" . $node->field_addendum['und'][$i]['filename'];
  $variable1 = $node->field_addendum['und'][$i]['filename'];
  if (isset($variable1)) {
    $result = $i + 1;
    echo "<a href='$variable2' target='_blank'>$result&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a>";}
  else {}
}
?>
```

The field_addendum is a "file" field type from a custom content type. I understand why I'm getting the notice: if the node only has 3 addendums, once the loop gets to $node->field_addendum['und'][3]['filename'] and onwards, there is nothing in the array.

Is there a way to get the number of files without having to loop through the array first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do the loop, personally I'd use a `foreach` statement. You can also compress your code a fair bit and make use of some API calls:

```
$options = array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'));
foreach (field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_addendum') as $index => $file) {
  echo l(($index + 1) . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', file_create_url($file['uri']), $options);
}
```

You could also use `count($node->field_addendum['und'])` to get the number of elements in the array if you want, but I think the above is a bit simpler.

Reference for API functions:

- [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7)

  > Returns the field items in the language they currently would be displayed.
- [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7)

  > Formats an internal or external URL link as an HTML anchor tag.
- [`file_create_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7)

  > Create the download path to a file.

Comment: Thanks Clive. Still working my way through the api, so this was very useful. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check if array element exist before assigment, and only if so, assign it, an this way avoid undefined offset:

```
  if (isset($node->field_addendum['und'][$i]['filename'])) {
     $variable1 = $node->field_addendum['und'][$i]['filename'];
    }
```